# Change to use prepared statement (mssql) in nodejs but not working

Tags: node.js, sql-server, prepared-statement

I'm rewriting this function into prepared statement

```
    let products = await pool.request().query("SELECT TOP (1000) article " +
        "FROM [ProductCatalogue_brand].[dbo].[CatalogueItems] " +
        "where article in (" + skus + ")");
    return products.recordsets;
```

the above function return the result successfully, i try to use prepare statement

```
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let products = await pool.request()
        .input('skus', sql.VarChar(8000), skus)
        .query("select article from [ProductCatalogue_brand].[dbo].[CatalogueItems] where Article in (@skus)");
    return products.recordsets;
```

but no records were found.

here is full source

```
var config = require('./dbconfig');
const sql = require('mssql');

//create a get product function form the database
async function getProducts(skus) {
    try {

        /*let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let products = await pool.request()
            .input('skus', sql.VarChar(8000), skus)
            .query("select article from [ProductCatalogue_brand].[dbo].[CatalogueItems] where Article in (@skus)");
        return products.recordsets;*/


        /*let products = await pool.request().query("SELECT TOP (1000) article " +
            "FROM [ProductCatalogue_brand].[dbo].[CatalogueItems] " +
            "where article in (" + skus + ")");
        return products.recordsets;*/
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

//export getProducts function
module.exports = {
    getProducts: getProducts
}
```

The skus is separated string is 'skus','sku2','sku3'

anyone know what is the problem?

------------------update still not work-------------------

```
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool);
        //convert skus to array
        var skuArray = skus.split(",");
        // Construct an object of parameters, using arbitrary keys
        var paramsObj = skuArray.reduce((obj, val, idx) => {
            obj[`id${idx}`] = val;
            ps.input(`id${idx}`, sql.VarChar(200));
            return obj;
        }, {});

        console.log(Object.keys(paramsObj).map((o) => {return '@'+o}).join(','));

        // Manually insert the params' arbitrary keys into the statement
        var stmt = 'select article from [ProductCatalogue_brand].[dbo].[CatalogueItems] where Article in (' + Object.keys(paramsObj).map((o) => {return '@'+o}).join(',') + ')';
        ps.prepare(stmt, function(err) {
            ps.execute(paramsObj, function(err, data) {
                console.log(data);
                ps.unprepare(function(err) {
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: You can't do `in(@variable)`, where @variable contains list - SQL takes it as single text to compare. You could use some construct with `string_split(@variable, ',')`.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter in prepared statement gets safely replaced as one item.

So if you use `(" + skus + ")` you get `... in ('skus','sku2','sku3')` and if you use `(@skus)` you get `... in ("'skus','sku2','sku3'")` (double quotes used for visibility and aren't valid syntax), which matches true if article equals `"'skus','sku2','sku3'"`.

Try placing multiple @params in statement based on number of items in skus. Assuming skus is list of strings:

```
const params = skus.map((x,i) => `@sku${i}`).join(", ") // If skus is string just replace skus with skus.split(",")
const stmt = `select article from [ProductCatalogue_brand].[dbo].[CatalogueItems] where Article in (${params})`
```

And then bind first item in `skus` to `@sku0`, second to `@sku1`, ...

Comment: no need to do something like .input('skus', sql.VarChar(8000), skus) ?

Comment: Its needed - do it in a loop for each item. Simpler solution for you particular usecase would be though not to mess with 'in' list, but to write getSingleProduct function and call it once for each search term. As long as there is less than ~20 items performance cost wouldn't be prohibitive.

Comment: i'updated the question, but it still not work